# Django print models constant array in template

Tags: python, django

I have a constant array in my model:

```
DELIVERY_TYPES = (
    ('self', u'one'),
    ('paid', u'two'),
    ('free', u'3')
)
```

in my django template I'am trying to render it:

```
<span style="font-size: 20px;">{{ DELIVERY_TYPES[shop.delivery_type] }}</span>
```

I get an error, how to print these values right?

Comment: Can you post your model where you have defined `DELIVERY_TYPES` and views from where you have sent the Model object to template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
{{ shop.get_delivery_type_display }}
```

See the docs on [`get_FOO_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) for more info.